# Does Android require a Google User account?

Tags: android

I'm designing an API for an Android app.  An iPhone requires a user to get an Apple ID, do Android mobile devices in the same way 'require' users to get a Google ID?

Ideally I want to be able to assume that users downloading our app on Android will have a Google account, so that we authentication via the Users and OAuth APIs is a snap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not required to have a Google account associated with an Android device, though most people probably do. You do need one if you download apps through the Market, but you can also side-load apps, use other markets like the Amazon App Store, etc.

Answer (score 6):

For both the Android phones that I've bought in the US (an HTC G1 and an HTC G2) it has forced me to enter my Google account information (or create a new Google account), before I could do *anything* on the device (similar to how the iPad forces you to connect it to iTunes before you can use it).

Some people suggest [clearing the data associated with all the Google apps](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/103007-android-without-google-account.html) on the phone to disconnect the device from the Google account, or you can just remove the account through Settings -> Accounts & Sync.

I suspect it boils down to exactly how the carrier delivers the phone to users.  If you want your app to be available globally then you should assume many users will NOT have a Google account.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, users need a Google ID to use Android Market. As far as I know, they do not need one to use other markets (such as Amazon). What are you authenticating?

Comment: I want to use the Users and OAuth APIs that are baked into Google App Engine, which is serving our API.  I am basically trying to assess a level of effort for registering/authenticating users - i.e., do we need to build a whole registration workflow into the app.